# How do i align a button beside textbox in VF using SLDS

Tags: visualforce, slds

I am trying to have a button beside a text box. Its basically a search box with a label and textbox and button. All of them need to be in same line.

The code below shows the button on the next line.

```
<div class="slds-grid ">
  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-1 slds-medium-size_1-of-1 slds-large-size_1-of-1 slds-p-top_medium">
    <div class="slds-box ">
      <div class="slds-form slds-form_horizontal ">
        <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-1 slds-medium-size_1-of-1 slds-large-size_1-of-1 slds-p-top_medium ">
          <div class="slds-form-element ">
            <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="searchTxt">Search Account</label>
            <div class="slds-form-element__control">
              <apex:inputText value="{!Searchtext}" id="searchTxt" styleclass="slds-input" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-1 slds-medium-size_1-of-1 slds-large-size_1-of-1  ">
          <apex:commandButton action="{!search}" value="Search " styleclass="slds-button slds-button_brand"
            rerender="searchresult" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think there are 2 options -- or you place your form element in same col, or you make 2 cols -- one with input and other with button. Please, check this nice link first. https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/utilities/grid/. It could be probably wise to post actual vs desired screenshot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by placing two grids in the same column.

```
<div class="slds-scope">
    <div class="slds-grid ">
       <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-1 slds-medium-size_1-of-1 slds-large-size_1-of-1 slds-p-top_medium">
           <div class="slds-box ">
              <div class="slds-form slds-form_horizontal ">
                  <div class="slds-grid slds-size_1-of-1 slds-medium-size_1-of-1 slds-large-size_1-of-1 slds-p-top_medium ">
                      <div class="slds-form-element slds-size_1-of-2">
                           <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="searchTxt">Search Account</label>
                              <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                                    <apex:inputText value="{!Searchtext}" id="searchTxt" styleclass="slds-input" />
                             </div>

                      </div>
                      <div class="slds-grid slds-size_1-of-2 slds-medium-size_1-of-2 slds-large-size_1-of-2 slds-p-horizontal_large ">
                          <apex:commandButton action="{!search}" value="Search " styleclass="slds-button slds-button_brand"
                                            rerender="searchresult" />
                      </div>
                 </div>
            </div>
       </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

I have also used padding to create some space between text box and button.

You can also refer [Padding in LDS](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/utilities/padding/#site-main-content) and [Grid in LDS](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/utilities/grid/#site-main-content)

Comment: Makes sense now ...

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the Search Button in the other line because you are using columns for each text and button as well

> class="slds-col" is doing the same for you

Put both the metadata in a single column and will do the trick

```
<div class="slds-scope">
            <div class="slds-grid ">
                <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-1 slds-medium-size_1-of-1 slds-large-size_1-of-1 slds-p-top_medium">
                    <div class="slds-box ">
                        <div class="slds-form slds-form_horizontal ">
                            <div class="slds-grid slds-size_1-of-1 slds-medium-size_1-of-1 slds-large-size_1-of-1 slds-p-top_medium ">
                                <div class="slds-form-element slds-size_1-of-2">
                                    <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="searchTxt">Search Account</label>
                                    <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                                        <apex:inputText value="{!Searchtext}" id="searchTxt" styleclass="slds-input" />
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                                <div class="slds-grid slds-size_1-of-2 slds-medium-size_1-of-2 slds-large-size_1-of-2 ">
                                    <apex:commandButton action="{!search}" value="Search " styleclass="slds-button slds-button_brand"
                                                        rerender="searchresult" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

You can also use padding to give the same between the text input and button.

refer below document for the same
[Padding](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/utilities/padding/)